# mapview: transparent na.color when displaying raster files

Tags: r, gis, raster, r-mapview

When I plot aerial photographs in `mapview` a black rectangle is displayed around the picture, which I believe contains NA values and which I would like to remove. Due to the lack of easily available example data I have uploaded my actual geotif [here](https://lfl.cloud.bayern.de/index.php/s/S1rkkMpP4bmPWAt) (password: 1_sillyQuestion).

```
test_image <- terra::rast("yourpath\\test-image.tif") %>% 
  satellite::brick()

viewRGB(test_image,
    r = 1,
    g = 2,
    b = 3,
    quantiles = NULL)
```

[image]

Using data provided with the `plainview` package, I am able to remove the grey area surrounding the raster (which I think is analogous to my issue) by setting the `na.color` argument to `"transparent"`.

Border present:

```
mapview::viewRGB(plainview::poppendorf, 4, 3, 2)
```

[image]

Border removed:

```
mapview::viewRGB(plainview::poppendorf, 4, 3, 2, na.color = "transparent")
```

[image]

Unfortunately this doesn't produce any changes, when applied to my problem:

```
viewRGB(gtiff_small,
    r = 1,
    g = 2,
    b = 3,
    quantiles = NULL,
    na.color = "transparent")
```

Any suggestions about how to remove the black rectangle around my aerial image will be much appreciated!

Comment: Your test-image lyr4 is presumably a mask as test-image[1,1,4] = 0 and [300,300, 4] = 255.

Comment: @Chris: thanks for your comment, but I'm not sure how to interpret it. Do you have a suggestion how to remove/make the black area transparent? It must be possible, as it displays fine in QGIS

Comment: I guess I'm just pointing out that you're interpreting the presence of the 4th lyr as though it were an alpha, values between 0:1, whereas they're not. Currently rebuilding my entire spatial stack so more later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`na.color` has no effect here because there aren't any NAs in the data. Your image is an RGB image where the black pixels are encoded `as rgb(0, 0, 0)` - black. The right thing to do is to specify a NA value upon the creation of the image (GDAL has an option to do this IIRC). Below is a solution that replaces all `rgb(0, 0, 0)` pixels with NA. But be careful, this will also set any real black pixels to NA (that's why it should really be done upon image creation).

```r
library(mapview)
library(leaflet)
library(raster)
#> Loading required package: sp

test_image <- terra::rast("/home/tim/Downloads/test-image.tif") %>% 
  raster::brick() %>%
  subset(c(1, 2, 3))

# set all values with 0 to NA
vals = values(test_image)
idx = which(rowSums(vals) == 0)
vals[idx, ] = cbind(NA, NA, NA)

test_image = setValues(test_image, vals)

viewRGB(test_image,
        r = 1,
        g = 2,
        b = 3,
        na.color = "transparent",
        quantiles = NULL)
#> Warning in rasterCheckSize(x, maxpixels = maxpixels): maximum number of pixels for Raster* viewing is 5e+05 ; 
#> the supplied Raster* has 19132224 
#>  ... decreasing Raster* resolution to 5e+05 pixels
#>  to view full resolution set 'maxpixels =  19132224 '
#> Warning in showSRID(uprojargs, format = "PROJ", multiline = "NO", prefer_proj =
#> prefer_proj): Discarded ellps WGS 84 in Proj4 definition: +proj=merc +a=6378137
#> +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +k=1 +units=m +nadgrids=@null
#> +wktext +no_defs +type=crs
#> Warning in showSRID(uprojargs, format = "PROJ", multiline = "NO", prefer_proj =
#> prefer_proj): Discarded datum World Geodetic System 1984 in Proj4 definition
#> Warning in raster::projectRaster(x, raster::projectExtent(x, crs =
#> sp::CRS(epsg3857)), : input and ouput crs are the same
```

[image]

```r
test_image
#> class      : RasterBrick 
#> dimensions : 4016, 4764, 19132224, 3  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
#> resolution : 0.1, 0.1  (x, y)
#> extent     : 1277489, 1277966, 6087025, 6087427  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> crs        : +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +k=1 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs 
#> source     : memory
#> names      : test.image_1, test.image_2, test.image_3 
#> min values :            0,            1,            0 
#> max values :          255,          255,          255
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>